# All permutations of a string with repetitions allowed

Tags: java, string, recursion, permutation

This is my recursive solution which returns a set of all permutations of a string. However, this implementation does not allow any repetitions. For instance for the input string `rs`, it will output only `{rs,sr}` whereas with repetitions allowed the correct output should be `{rs,sr,rr,ss}`. Can the same code as below, with some minor modification/additions, be used to address the above issue?

```
Set<String> findCombinations(String time){
    if(time.length() == 1){
        return new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(time));
    }
    char firstChar = time.charAt(0);
    Set<String> combos = new HashSet<>();
    Set<String> currentCombo = findCombinations(time.substring(1));

    Iterator<String> iter = currentCombo.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        String currentStr = iter.next();
        for(int i = 0; i <= currentStr.length(); i++){
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(currentStr);
            combos.add(builder.insert(i, firstChar).toString());
        }        
    } 
    return combos;
}
```

I understand that there are other posts with solutions to this issue. What I am looking for is the minimal set of changes to the above code required to obtain the desired result.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i <= currentStr.length(); i++){` is this correct ?

Comment: Permutations are all possible 'positions' in the some set of elements without repetitions, so you're looking for complete variations with repetitions.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yes it is. Check out the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#insert-int-char-) for details.